# InterstitialAd InvalidServerResponse "Invalid XML"

Tags: c#, uwp, interstitial

I'm trying to display and Interstitial Ad on a UWP app and I'm getting an error coming back from the Ad Request:

- Error Code = "InvalidServerResponse"
- Error Message =  "Invalid XML"

My Code is copied from https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/interstitial-ads

```
        // instantiate an InterstitialAd
        InterstitialAd MyVideoAd = new InterstitialAd();

        // wire up all 4 events, see below for function templates
        MyVideoAd.AdReady += MyVideoAd_AdReady;
        MyVideoAd.ErrorOccurred += MyVideoAd_ErrorOccurred;
        MyVideoAd.Completed += MyVideoAd_Completed;
        MyVideoAd.Cancelled += MyVideoAd_Cancelled;

        var MyAppId = "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab";
        var MyAdUnitId = "11389925";

        // pre-fetch an ad 30-60 seconds before you need it
        MyVideoAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, MyAppId, MyAdUnitId);
```

What am I missing??